# Como usar um parâmetro com hífen em um Helper HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Olá estou  utilizando  o **Data Annotation** do ASP.NET MVC na  linguagem  C#, porém  não estou  conseguindo passar o paramento `data-toggle` no *helper* **`CheckBoxFor`**:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ReceberEmail, 
                           new { @class ="form-control", @data-toggle ="toggle"})
```

No meu Model o  código encontra-se da seguinte  forma:

```
[Display(Name = "Receber Emails ?")]
public virtual Boolean ReceberEmail { get; set; }
```

Teria alguma forma de passar esse parâmetro pelo **Data Annotation**?

Comment: Já consegui, basta alterar o  - pelo _ (under line) 
as vezes são algumas  coisas bobas que nos prendem  no  codigo

Comment: Marcos, escreva uma resposta para sua pergunta.

Comment: Opa, eu tinha respondido a mesma coisa, mas removi, responde aí

Comment: @LINQ , respoderam aqui, ai marquei  como  correto, grato.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o seu código conforme abaixo:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.ReceberEmail, new { @class ="form-control", @data_toggle ="toggle"})
```

Propriedades como **@data-toggle** devem ser passadas com o underscore, ou seja **@data_toggle**.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, @sérgio-lopes, eu havia conseguido aqui fazendo isso  rsrs depois de  umas  horas quebrando  a  cabeça, grato pela atenção